# How to get the full path of the currently open scene file in the 3dsmax sdk?

Tags: c++, sdk, path, filenames, 3dsmax

I can do `GetIGameInterface()->GetSceneFileName()`, but it only gives me the file name. How do I get the full path, for example c:\myfiles\test.max ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

GetCOREInterface()->GetCurFilePath();